# Django - Annotate and cast an encrypted TextField to a FloatField to 2 decimal places

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-postgresql, pgcrypto

I'm using [Django pgcrypto fields](https://github.com/incuna/django-pgcrypto-fields) to encrypt an amount value in a model 
`Invoice` as follows:

```
from pgcrypto import fields

class Invoice(models.Model):
    # Some other fields
    amount_usd = fields.TextPGPSymmetricKeyField(default='')

    objects = InvoicePGPManager()  # Manager used for PGP Fields
```

I'm using a`TextPGPSymmetricKeyField` because I've to store the value as a float and `django-pgcrypto-fields` does not have an equivalent for FloatField.

Now I need to pass this `amount_usd` value via an API and I've to restrict the decimals upto two places.

I've tried using the following:

```
Invoice.objects.all().values('amount_usd').annotate(
    amount_to_float=Cast('amount_usd', FloatField())
)
```

But this gives an error as bytes(encrypted data) cannot be converted to float.

I tried using this as well:

```
from django.db.models import Func

class Round(Func):
    function = 'ROUND'
    template='%(function)s(%(expressions)s, 2)'


Invoice.objects.all().annotate(PGPSymmetricKeyAggregate(
            'amount_usd')).annotate(amount=Cast(
            'amount_usd__decrypted', FloatField())).annotate(
            amount_final = Round('amount'))
```

I get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: function round(double precision, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: ...sd, 'ultrasecret')::double precision AS "amount", ROUND(pgp_...
                                                         ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Is there any way to convert the encrypted field to a FloatField of upto 2 decimal places?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error says: `double precision AS "amount"` 
That's because you're converting `amount_usd` to a `FloatField` which converts to a double precision in SQL.

Try using a `DecimalField` (converts to type numeric in SQL) with it's arguments.

```
Invoices.objects.all().annotate(amount=Cast(
    PGPSymmetricKeyAggregate('amount_usd'),
    DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)))
```

Check the documentation here: [Django DecimalField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield)